# Non-linear system of four equations with three unknowns

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

I have the following non-linear equation:

$e^{\beta_0+\beta_1x+\beta_2*y}+C = e^{\mu_0+\mu_1x+\mu_2*y}$.

$\beta_i$ is known, but $\mu_0$, $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are parameters we want to estimate. *x* and *y* are two binary variables, *x*={0,1} and *y*={0,1}. For the different combinations of *x* and *y* we get the following 4 equations:

1) *x*=0, *y*=0:   $e^{\beta_0}+C = e^{\mu_0}$.

2) *x*=1, *y*=0:   $e^{\beta_0+\beta_1}+C = e^{\mu_0+\mu_1}$.

3) *x*=0, *y*=1:   $e^{\beta_0+\beta_2}+C = e^{\mu_0+\mu_2}$.

4) *x*=1, *y*=1:   $e^{\beta_0+\beta_1+\beta_2}+C = e^{\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2}$.

*C* is a constant we can manually adjust. Does this system of equations have a solution?

Comment: Is your 3rd equation correct? Is it $\beta_0\beta_2$ or $\beta_0+\beta_2$?

Comment: @MrYouMath: Thank you much for that, fixed it!

Comment: There is a solution if and only if $$(e^{\beta_0+\beta_1+\beta_2}+C)(e^{\beta_0}+C)=e^{2\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2}=(e^{\beta_0+\beta_1}+C)(e^{\beta_0+\beta_2}+C)$$ which happens if and only if $$C=0\quad\text{or}\quad e^{\beta_0+\beta_1+\beta_2}+e^{\beta_0}=e^{\beta_0+\beta_1}+e^{\beta_0+\beta_2}$$ The latter condition is equivalent to $$e^{\beta_1+\beta_2}+1=e^{\beta_1}+e^{\beta_2}$$ which happens if and only if $$\beta_1=0\quad\text{or}\quad\beta_2=0$$ Finally the system of equations (1)-(2)-(3)-(4) has a solution if and only if $C=0$, and then the solution is $\mu_i=\beta_i$, ...

Comment: ... or if $\beta_1=0$ and then $\mu_1=0$, $\mu_0$ is determined by (1) and $\mu_2$ is determined by (3) or (4),  or if $\beta_2=0$ and then $\mu_2=0$, $\mu_0$ is determined by (1) and $\mu_1$ is determined by (2) or (4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Start with your first equation and use it to eliminate $\mathrm{e}^{\mu_0}$ from the other equations.

Then use the second equation to eliminate $\mathrm{e}^{\mu_1}$ from the other equations.

At the end you will get one equation with beta only. You will need to check if this equation can be true for a particular choice of $C$. If that is not possible you will need to use non-linear regressions to get parameters $\mu_j$.

Main idea of non-linear regression (here non-linear least squares): Define a new function $$F(\mu_0,\mu_1,\mu_2,C)=(e^{\beta_0}+C-e^{\mu_0})^2+(e^{\beta_0+\beta_1}+C - e^{\mu_0+\mu_1})^2+(e^{\beta_0+\beta_2}+C - e^{\mu_0+\mu_2})^2+(e^{\beta_0+\beta_1+\beta_2}+C - e^{\mu_0+\mu_1+\mu_2})^2.$$

The goal is to minimize this function (this is a non-linear least squares solution).  So you need to find the gradient of $F$ and set it to zero. The resulting system of equations can be solved by using for example Newton-Raphson procedure. Note that this procedure is quite inaccurate for only four data points. If you have more datapoints you can try to get a better fit.

Comment: Thank you for answering! Yes, so it is true that this system might not be solvable for all choices of C, correct?

Comment: I thinkt that it is not solvable. But you should give it a try substitute all equations into the last equation and try to solve it for $C$. You can use maple or wolfram alpha for this purpose.

Comment: should we not have *x* and *y* in your function *F* above? I mean, since you are talking about fitting the function to data?

Comment: No, you allready plugged in your $x,y$ values (we received data point equations from this). You are not looking for $x,y$ values but rather values for $\mu_j,C$ to minimize the error.

Comment: @MrYouMath "if this equation can be true for a particular choice of C" It appears it can very rarely be true, see my comment on main.